Find a function $u$ that solves this boundary value problem (with a weak formulation).
This exercise is paraphrased from page 8 of Finite Elements: An Introduction Volume 1 (Becker, Cary, Oden):

The identity function is defined by $\mathbf I (x) = x$. Concatenating functions will be the Hadamard product (matching, element-wise multiplication of image points), rather than composition.
$H$ is the space of all functions of form $[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ that are smooth, square integrable, and vanish on the endpoints. Have $u, v \in H$. Solve for $u$ such that$$-u'' = \mathbf I $$
and the weak formulation
$$ \int \limits_0^1 (-u'' - \mathbf I) v \,dx = 0 \;\;\;\; \text{for all } v \in H$$
is satisfied.

Answer: In this case, the weak form is identical to the strong form, and the second condition is superfluous. We solve a standard boundary-value problem. Take indefinite integrals:$$-u = \int \!\!\! \int  -u'' \, dx = \int \!\!\! \int \mathbf I \, dx = {\mathbf I^3 \over 6} + A \mathbf I + B$$
apply boundary conditions at $x = 0$:$$-u(0) = 0= 0 + 0 + B $$
which implies $B = 0$. Apply boundary boundary conditions at $x = 1$: $$ - u(1) = 0 = {1 \over 6} + A$$ which implies $A = -1/6$. Then we have $$u = {\mathbf I - \mathbf I^3\over 6} $$

Do we not need to weak formulation for this problem, and does this solution hold? Keep in mind, there is a part (b) to this question that may be harder and require the weak formulation, so it can make sense that this question can be solved so directly.
